# iOS 13.1 Crash in AVAudio Player

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, ios13

My App is crashing on iOS 13.1 when i trace a issue then found App is crashing because of `AVAudioPlayer`.

Below Is My Player Setup.

```
if let wrongURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "wrongAudio", withExtension: "mp3")
        {
            do {
                wrongMusicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: wrongURL)
                wrongMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            }
            catch
            {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

Here All things found correctly but crash when `AVAudioPlayer` try to initialise with `URL`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I found a crash issue in `AVAudioPlayer` with iOS 13.1.

Here Is Solution

Why My `AVAudioPlayer` crash? because

I initialise `AVAudioPlayer` like

```
var wrongMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

and then i try to reassign `wrongMusicPlayer` as below

```
wrongMusicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: wrongURL)
```

And my app get crash.

**Solution**

If you initialise your `AVAudioPlayer` like `var wrongMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()` OR `wrongMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()` in any method then please remove it and just Declare like `var wrongMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!`.

Comment: Can you share in objective C?

Answer (score 3):

iOS 13.2, which be released today, fixes this issue.

Comment: I didn't experienced the issue of a crash on iOS 13.2 but on objective c if you do a alloc init first, then on other line you do a avaudioplayer initwith, the object that had the audioplayer initialized was set to nil and the additional init was not working at all, so I had to change to use alloc and initWithData or initWithContentsOfURL to be used immediately after the alloc.

Comment: updating to ios 13.2 and XCode 11.2 fixed this issue

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, Rakesh! 
It's amazing!
My game broke on iPhone with iOS 13.1.2. But in simulator it's work. On physical device - no! 
I read a lot of forums, online books, docs, etc.

And this small fix really helped me: 
I changed `var player = AVAudioPlayer()` to `var player: AVAudioPlayer!`

p.s. guys wrote about problem with threads but this case is simpler

Answer (score 1):

The same issue happens with Objective C code.

Previously  musicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] init];
would work but will now cause a crash in iOS13. The crash happens later on when using one of the other init methods like initWithContentsOfURL.

**Removing the [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] init] fixes the issue.**