# iOS13.1 AVAudioPlayer objective-c EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, iphone, avaudioplayer

iOS13.1 AVAudioPlayer objective-c Error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48)
```

AVAudioPlayer+Extension.h file:

```
@interface AVAudioPlayer (Extension)

- (instancetype)initWithFilepath:(NSString*)filepath
                       delegate:(id<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>)delegate;
```

AVAudioPlayer+Extension.m file:

```
#import "AVAudioPlayer+Extension.h"

@implementation AVAudioPlayer (Extension)

@implementation AVAudioPlayer (Extension)

- (instancetype)initWithFilepath:(NSString*)filepath
                        delegate:(id<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>)delegate {

    NSError *error;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                                   error:&error];

    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"AVAudioPlayer init failed %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return nil;
    }


    player.currentTime = 0;
    player.delegate = delegate;

    return player;
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem! Did you fix it?

Comment: Same problem, started today after upgrading to iOS 13.1

Comment: We found [solution for swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58110827/ios-13-1-crash-in-avaudio-player). I think problem the same with AVAudioPlayer *player