# At New iOS Versions AVAudioPlayer Arrays gets Bad Access Error But Why

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I was using the following function to make multiple audio players ready.

But when run the code at new iOS Versions  I am getting ***Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48)*** from line
 ***players[i] = player***

It still runs at old iOS versions without a problem.

```swift
func loadMusicToAPlayer(i: Int, name: String){
    let s = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType:nil)!
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: s )
    do {
        let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        players[i] = player
        players[i].prepareToPlay()
        players[i].isMeteringEnabled = true
    } catch {
        print("couldn't load music file :( ")
    }
 }
```

Comment: show your code where you create players property

Comment: I am creating player array like that before hand, **var players            : [AVAudioPlayer]   = []**,  **players.append(AVAudioPlayer())**, as much as I need in a loop.

Comment: `AVAudioPlayer()` crash on early version of iOS13. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58110827/ios-13-1-crash-in-avaudio-player https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58144735/avaudioplayer-crashes-on-ios-13 etc.

Comment: Yeah I notice that if I create players like **players.append(player)** it works but I have to change heck of a code now. Because I was calling function from multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

I was creating an array like this before using the function above.
I was doing it like this

```swift
for k in 0..< audioList.count {
    players.append(AVAudioPlayer())
}
```

because sometimes I was changing the name of
audio of a player. To do it easily I was separated audio loading function.

Now, I am creating player array like  this.
And changed audio name in revised version of function in question.

```swift
func loadAudio(name: [String]){

    for k in 0..< name.count {
        let s = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name[k], ofType:nil)!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: s )

        do {
            let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            players.append(player)
        } catch { print("could not load audio file"}
    }
}
```