# Cannot play audio file without app crashing on device running ios 13

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have an app being used by people to receive orders with it needing to make a continuous sound until staff attend to it. It was working for two months then just started crashing a lot. For whatever reason, it runs fine on an iPad but not on iPhones running a recent operating system.

When this bit of code gets called it crashes:

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "alert.mp3", ofType: nil) else { return }
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
do {
    self.alertSoundEffect = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
} catch let err {
    print("err: \(err)")
}

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.alertSoundEffect.numberOfLoops = -1
    self.alertSoundEffect.prepareToPlay()
    self.alertSoundEffect.play()
}
```

The fix online to declare the alertSoundEffect variable like this:

```
 private var alertSoundEffect : AVAudioPlayer!
```

has not worked at all.

I tried moving everything but the line:

```
self.alertSoundEffect.play()
```

to viewDidLoad as I thought maybe that code couldn't get called more than once, but it didn't help.

Specifically, the compiler highlights this line when it crashes:

```
self.alertSoundEffect = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
```

I tried using try AVAudioPlayer where it takes a Data object as a parameter or with including the type of audio file to be played, but that did not change anything.

When I try the AVAudioPlayer's delegate and declare it like this:

```
self.alertSoundEffect.delegate = self
```

right before the first lines of code I shared above Xcode highlights this line instead when it reliably crashes.

What else should I try?

Comment: Show the crash log, please.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your `path` is wrong.
Try this:

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "alert", ofType: "mp3") else { return }
```

Also, if your audio file is short, like less than 30s, then try not to call `self.alertSoundEffect.prepareToPlay()`. Just call `self.alertSoundEffect.play()` right away.

Since iOS 13, this was causing a bug in my app, since I have notification sounds which are 3-10 seconds long.

Answer (score 0):

If you initialise your AVAudioPlayer like var wrongMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer() OR wrongMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer() in any method then please remove it and just Declare like var wrongMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!.

[iOS 13.1 Crash in AVAudio Player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58110827/ios-13-1-crash-in-avaudio-player)