# iOS 13 Crash SKAudioNode with autoplay deactivated

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, avaudioplayer, skaudionode

Since iOS 13 my App crashes on `view.presentScene(scene)` (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)`). This only happens, if the scene has a `SKAudioNode` with autoplay deactivated.

The error can be reproduced by creating a new Project->Game with SpriteKit. Just add a `SKAudioNode` to the `GameScene.sks` and deactivate autoplay.

This might be related to [iOS 13.1 Crash in AVAudio Player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58110827/ios-13-1-crash-in-avaudio-player).